# JavaFX - javafx.print.PrinterJob.createPrinterJob() is always null on mac

Tags: java, macos, javafx, printing

I am printing nodes using JavaFX PrinterJob, like this:

```
    /**
 * @param node
 */
public static final void print(Node node)
        throws NoSuchMethodException, InstantiationException, IllegalAccessException, InvocationTargetException {
    Printer printer = Printer.getDefaultPrinter();
    PageLayout pageLayout = printer.createPageLayout(Paper.A4, PageOrientation.LANDSCAPE,
            Printer.MarginType.HARDWARE_MINIMUM);
    PrinterJob job = PrinterJob.createPrinterJob();

    if (job != null && job.showPrintDialog(CommonConstants.geMasterStage())) {
        boolean success = job.printPage(pageLayout, node);
        if (success) {
            job.endJob();

        }
    }
}
```

Which works fine on windows, But, `Printer.getDefaultPrinter();` is always null on mac,, so i made sure that the printer is available, which it is, and `Printer.getAllPrinters()` returns empty array.

It is good to note that `java.awt.print.PrinterJob.getPrinterJob()` works fine on both windows and mac.

what is the issue or what i am doing wrong ?

Comment: It works fine for me. Do you have a printer installed? In that case `Printer.getAllPrinters()` should return a non empty list.

Comment: @JoséPereda yes i have,, and its working fine with java.awt printer job,,, thats weird

Comment: I'm getting same error, did you solve it?

Comment: @pcambre nope,, we implemented something else,,

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem and whenever I check available printers using `Printer.getAllPrinters()`, it shows all available printers but `createPrinterJob()` always returns null.

So I did reset Printing System by right click on Printers under `Printers & Scanners` settings on `System Preferences` in MacOS. After resetting printing system, Added printers again to the Printers list. Then ran `createPrinterJob()` again on Java and never received null after that.

Comment: This worked for me. Since I didn't use Migration Assistant to set up this M1 MBP, no printers had been set up. Once that was done, things worked as they had before.

Answer (score 0):

I'm get the same problem, too. It is still not solved. But I found that it can get printer after I refresh printer list in console.  I add a line before createPrinterjob(), it work sometimes (not always).

"Runtime.getRuntime().exec("lpstat -p -d")"